# GCP Cloud Build publishing single event for each Cloud Function deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

We have a microservice deployed using Cloud Build consisting of several Cloud Functions. Till yesterday we used to get a single pub/sub event published into cloud-builds pub/sub topic informing us of the status of the build (SUCCESS/FAIL) but now we see events into cloud-builds pub/sub topic for each Cloud Function and also the final status of the build.

This change produces 10s of email notifications whereas we expect one notification per build.

Not sure what was the change done from GCP's side (Could not find any documentation informing the new change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug fix (or a feature deployment). It's normal. In fact, for many months, each time that you deploy a Cloud Functions, a Cloud Build is trigger to build it (I'm in the alpha to see the Cloud Build logs automatically created by the `gcloud functions deploy` command).

So now, because a Cloud Build is triggered to build the Cloud Functions, it's normal to publish a notification as any Cloud Build jobs. If you deploy an App Engine, you should see the same thing (because `gcloud app deploy` also trigger a Cloud Build for the deployment).

Comment: Looks like it.  To avoid flood of email notifications I just had to figure out a field to filter out the events IDC about.